# Probability of two events in time series: Which event is more likely to occur?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Let $P_i(t) \in [0, 1]$ be probability of event $i = 1, 2$ occur at time $t \geq 0$, both of which satisfy $P_i(\infty) = 0$, and $\int_0^\infty P_i(t) \, dt < \infty$.

I would like to know which event is more likely to occur over the infinite time horizon.
Does the following ratio make sense for evaluation?
$$
\frac{\mathbb{E}[P_1(t)]}{\mathbb{E}[P_2(t)]}
=
\frac{\int_0^\infty P_1(t) \, dt}{\int_0^\infty P_2(t) \, dt}
$$

Does the ratio $\mathbb{E}[P_1(t)] \, / \, \mathbb{E}[P_2(t)]$ make sense because $P_i(t)$ are not random variables?

Or directly, is $\bigl(\int_0^\infty P_1(t) \, dt\bigr) \, / \, \bigl(\int_0^\infty P_2(t) \, dt\bigr)$ appropriate?

Comment: Where you say "is likely to occur", do you mean "is more likely to occur"? If not, what do you mean by that? Both could be likely to occur? And where is the threshold for being "likely to occur"?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. "is more likely to occur". I revised my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If $\ T_i\ $ is the time when event $i$ occurs, then $\ T_i\ $ is a random variable with $\ P_i(t)=\lim_\limits{x\rightarrow t-}P\left(x<T_i\le t\right)\ $, which cannot be non-zero at more than a countable number of points.  Therefore $\ \int_\limits{0}^\infty P_i(t)\,dt=0\ $, and the expression
  $$
  \frac{\int_\limits{0}^\infty P_1(t)\,dt}{\int_\limits{0}^\infty P_2(t)\,dt}
  $$
  is undefined.
- As long as $\ P_2(t)\ne 0\ $ the ratio $\ \frac{\mathbb{E}\left(P_1(t)\right)}{\mathbb{E}\left(P_2(t)\right)}\ $ is a well-defined quantity. However, since (as you have realised) neither $\ P_1(t)\ $ nor $\ P_2(t)\ $ are random variables, $\ \mathbb{E}\left(P_i(t)\right)\ $ is simply equal to $\ P_i(t)\ $ (not $\ \int_\limits{0}^\infty P_i(t)\,dt\ $) and therefore
  $$
  \frac{\mathbb{E}\left(P_1(t)\right)}{\mathbb{E}\left(P_2(t)\right)}= \frac{P_1(t)}{P_2(t)}\ .
  $$
  Note, however that $\ P_2(t)\ $ can only be non-zero at no more than a countable number of values of $\ t\ $, and will be *identically* zero if $\ T_2\ $ has a continuous distribution.
- The only reasonable meaning I can think of for the expression $\ P_i(\infty)\ $ is $\ \lim_\limits{t\rightarrow\infty}P\left(T_i>t\right)\ $, which is the probability that event $\ i\ $ never occurs. If this is not what you intended it to mean, you will need to explain exactly what you did intend it to mean. But if $\ P_i(\infty)\ =\lim_\limits{t\rightarrow\infty}P\left(T_i>t\right)\ $ is the correct interpretation, then $\ P_1(\infty)= P_2(\infty)=0\ $ means that both events $1$ and $2$ are *certain* to occur at some finite time, so neither is *more* likely than the other to occur "over the infinite time horizon".